# Почему не удаляется папка Java посредством метода delete()

Tags: java

Имеется такая ситуация. Есть папка, в которой проводятся действия. После этого папка переименовывается. Далее ее следует удалить. Однако метод delete() возвращает false. С чем связана проблема. Никакие файлы из этой папки не открыты на компьютере. Привожу код ниже:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class FolderCreator {
    private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "D:\\JavaStudy\\";
    private static final String FOLDER_NAME = "folder";
    private static final String ZIP_NAME = "\\output.zip";
    private static final String NEW_FOLDER_NAME = "folder_new";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME);
        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdir();
        try (FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + "\\file1");
             FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + "\\file2");
             FileOutputStream fos3 = new FileOutputStream(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + "\\file3");
             ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + ZIP_NAME));
             FileInputStream fin1 = new FileInputStream(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + "\\file1");
             FileInputStream fin2 = new FileInputStream(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + "\\file2");
             FileInputStream fin3 = new FileInputStream(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + "\\file3")) {
            fos1.write("Some Content1".getBytes());
            fos2.write("Some Content2".getBytes());
            fos3.write("Some Content3".getBytes());
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file1"));
            byte[] buf = new byte[200];
            fin1.read(buf);
            zos.write(buf);
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file2"));
            fin2.read(buf);
            zos.write(buf);
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file3"));
            fin3.read(buf);
            zos.write(buf);
            zos.closeEntry();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Упс, ошибочка :)");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
       
        File newFolder = new File(FOLDER_PATH + NEW_FOLDER_NAME);
        boolean flag = folder.renameTo(newFolder);

        for (File file : Objects.requireNonNull(newFolder.listFiles())) {
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
        }
        boolean b = newFolder.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас папка не удаляется, потому что она не пустая - сначала надо удалить из нее все файлы.
Вообще, используйте `java.nio.file.Path`, `java.nio.file.Files` и другие классы из `java.nio` пакета для работы с файлами. Методы `Files` кидают эксепшены если что-то не удалось сделать - это намного удобнее, чем гадать почему методы `File` вернули `false`

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку по поводу классов для работы с файлами, как можете заметить, я уже дал ответ на свой же вопрос и да, решение именно связано с файлами в папке, вы правы.

Comment: Да, я пока писал ответ, Вы уже добавили свой :). Но я решил оставить свой ответ из-за комментария о Path и Files

Comment: Тогда примем Ваш ответ, спасибо и успехов!

Comment: Спасибо, и Вам!

Answer (score 2):

**Возможные ошибки в FolderCreator.java**:

- Ошибка 1: обработка исключений

Код использует блок `try-with-resources` для обработки операций ввода-вывода. Однако блок `catch` только выводит сообщение на консоль и генерирует исключение `RuntimeException`. Это не очень хорошая практика, поскольку она не предоставляет никакой значимой информации об ошибке. Лучше записать сообщение об ошибке и трассировку стека в файл или на консоль.

- Ошибка 2: разделитель пути к файлу

В коде используется жестко заданный разделитель путей к файлам (`\\`) для создания путей к файлам. Это может вызвать проблемы при запуске кода в разных операционных системах. Лучше использовать константу `File.separator`, чтобы убедиться, что используется правильный разделитель пути к файлу.

- Ошибка 3: файл не найден

В коде предполагается, что входные файлы (`file1`, `file2` и `file3`) существуют в указанной папке. Если файлы не существуют, код выдаст исключение `FileNotFoundException`. Лучше проверить, существуют ли файлы, прежде чем пытаться их прочитать.

- Ошибка 4: переименование файла

Код пытается переименовать папку в `folder_new`. Если `folder_new` уже существует, метод `renameTo()` вернет `false`, и код не обработает этот случай. Перед попыткой переименовать папку лучше проверить, существует ли папка `_new`.

- Ошибка 5: удаление файла

Код пытается удалить `folder_new` после печати путей к файлам. Однако, если какой-либо из файлов в папке все еще открыт, метод удаления завершится ошибкой и вернет `false`. Перед попыткой удалить папку лучше закрыть все открытые файлы.

**Как исправить**

- Ошибка 1:

```
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while performing I/O operations: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

- Ошибка 2:

```
    private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "D:" + File.separator + "JavaStudy" + File.separator;
```

- Ошибка 3:

```
    File file1 = new File(FOLDER_PATH + FOLDER_NAME + "\\file1");
    if (!file1.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found: " + file1.getPath());
    }
```

- Ошибка 4:

```
    File newFolder = new File(FOLDER_PATH + NEW_FOLDER_NAME);
    if (newFolder.exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Folder already exists: " + newFolder.getPath());
    }
    boolean flag = folder.renameTo(newFolder);
    if (!flag) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to rename folder: " + folder.getPath());
    }
```

- Ошибка 5:

```
    for (File file : Objects.requireNonNull(newFolder.listFiles())) {
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
        file.close();
    }
    boolean b = newFolder.delete();
    if (!b) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to delete folder: " + newFolder.getPath());
    }
```

Comment: Подскажите, вы внимательно изучили код? Данная папка и файлы в ней создаются в самой программе, поэтому нет необходимости делать дополнительные проверки на существование. Да, это хорошая практика, согласен, но в данном случае это не причина проблемы. По поводу 5 ошибки. Вы написали file.close() для файлов в папке. Но у класса File нет же метода close(). Это ведь не поток, и ваш код не скомпилируется. Надеюсь на ваш ответ